# Lubuntu wine installation error

Tags: apt, lubuntu, wine, dpkg

When I was trying to install wine software in Lubuntu 14.10, I got the following error message without any specific reason. Can you please tell me how to resolve this problem and can I continue the wine installation without any further hindrance? Because, I am a newbie in Linux.

```
soorej@soorej-HP-Pavilion-dv6000-RZ901PA-ACJ:~$ sudo apt-get install wine
[sudo] password for soorej: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you try to run updates while the system is already doing it.  My Lubuntu install checks for updates each morning around 8 am - I didn't explicitly ask for it to do this, so I assume it is a default - and I've seen this message if I try to do similar things while it's running.